# How to sum a number until it becomes a whole number and count how many times it was summed?

Tags: vb.net

My task in VB.NET is as follows: Sum a number until it becomes a whole number and count how many times it was summed

Sorry, I know that is not that hard but I am new to coding

example:
I have this number 4.25

sum until he gets a whole number: 4.25 + 4.25 + 4.25 + 4.25 = 17
and count how many times he was sumed: 4 times

How to do that in VB.NET ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone in your class might tackle it this way...

If you look at the number as a fraction—from your example 4¼—you can see that you would have to multiply by the denominator (4) to get a whole number.

So, all you need to do is convert the fractional part to the simplest fraction and use the denominator.

```
Module Module1

    Dim decSep As String = Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

    Public Function GCD(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
        ' Copied from https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/greatest-common-divisor/vb-net/
        'TODO: Consider using a more efficient algorithm.
        If a = 0 Then
            Return b
        End If

        While b <> 0
            If a > b Then
                a -= b
            Else
                b -= a
            End If
        End While

        Return a

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ")
        Dim inp = Console.ReadLine()
        'TODO: Check that the input has a decimal separator with digits after it.

        Dim fracPart = inp.Substring(inp.IndexOf(decSep) + 1)

        Dim numerator = Convert.ToInt64(fracPart)
        Dim denominator = CLng(Math.Pow(10, fracPart.Length))
        Dim a = GCD(numerator, denominator)

        Dim mult = denominator / a

        Dim orig = Decimal.Parse(inp)
        Console.WriteLine($"You need to add {inp} to itself {mult} times to get the whole number {mult * orig}.")

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Sample run:

```
Enter a number: 1.6125
You need to add 1.6125 to itself 80 times to get the whole number 129.
```

Comment: @Scacs22 Please note that [Lajos Arpad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74422394/1115360) is closer to the wording of the task.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a counter, increment it each time you add `sum` to `sum`:

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 1
While sum <> Int(sum)
    cnt = cnt + 1
    sum = sum + original
End While
```

Comment: I have not worked with VB.net in the last 6 years, so maybe there are syntax errors. Let me know if there are such problems.